# What is the meaning of the information that I get by printing an Object in Java?

Tags: java, object, hash, tostring

Lets say i have this code :

```
Integer[] a= new Integer[5];
System.Out.println(((Object)a).toString());
```

the output is get is

```
[Integer@89fbe3
```

what is the meaning of 89fbe3 ? is this some kind of address ? hash code? is it unique for each object? , and if so- if its a multi-threaded program , is it still unique ?

thanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's the memory address of the object which is what the default toString() implemented in the Object class does. It is also the default hashCode().

Comment: I was going to downvote but it's not *technically* wrong.  But it's misleading.  It's only because arrays use the default hashCode that it's the memory address.

Comment: It is not (necessarily) the memory address. It's up to the JVM. (I suspect that it's never the memory address, actually.)

Comment: that's why I said it was the default toString() and hashCode() defined in the base Object type. Because he can obviously override any of those methods to produce different results.

Comment: So , it is true only for arrays?

Comment: @RanZilber:  No, it's true for any object whose class hierarchy has not somewhere overridden the default `hashCode()` or `toString()` method.

Comment: @Jesus no, he can't override the methods. Not for array classes anyway.

Comment: Look at the example in the question. It's an odd number. Clearly that isn't the actual memory address.

Answer (score 4):

It's the result of `System.identityHashCode(Object x);`

which is the default implementation of every object's hashCode()...

from the Object javadoc:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Comment: This covers all of the bases.  `[I` is actually what you get when you do `new int[0].getClass().getName()`.  +1.

Comment: ope! & thanks for the format fixup. :)

Answer (score 3):

The 89fbe3 is a hex version of the hash code.  The `[I` means an array of ints (I'm surprised you get that with an `Integer[]`, are you sure it wasn't an `int[]`?)

Some others:

- `[L<typename>;`: an array of reference type "typename" (e.g. `[Ljava.lang.Integer`)
- `[J`: an array of longs
- `[B`: an array of bytes

etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is the identity hash code of the object (you can think of it as the address of the object), along with some type information.

[ = array
I = Integer

Answer (score 1):

I think that while technically all the answers are correct, the real answer is "NO".  This number has no meaning and you can make absolutely no assumptions about it.

Comment: So is there any way to determine between two arrays in runtime?

Comment: The number is the hash code in hex, which for a method that doesn't override hash code is the (somewhat) unique object ID. This can be used to see if two objects are the same instance.

Comment: @RanZilber I think you accidentally the question.

Comment: It's good for checking whether the two variables you assumed to be referring to the same instance, actually do.

Comment: @Steve Kuo '==' can be used to see if 2 objects are the same instance. equals() can be used to see if two objects are "the same" according to their creator.  I don't know what the default toString() can be used for.

Comment: @biziclop what is wrong with '=='???

Comment: I think this is a correct answer as well.  If you need to absolutely identify an Object you need to retain a reference to it and use `==` to see if it's the same as another Object.  Just beware of memory leaks taking that route.

Comment: @MK I was thinking about printing the default object string into a debug log file for manual observation, not using it in actual code.