# Java char[] toString

Tags: java, char, tostring

I'm playing arround with `char[]` in Java, and using the folowing sample code:

```
char[] str = "Hello World !".toCharArray();
System.out.println(str.toString());
System.out.println(str);
```

I get the following output:

```
[C@4367e003
Hello World !
```

And I have some questions about it:

1. What does `[C@4367e003` stands for? Is it a memory address? What's the meaning of the digits? What's the meaning of `[C@`?
2. I always thought that calling `println()` on an object would call the toString method of this object but it doesn't seems to be the case?

Comment: new String(chararray); creates a string from a char array,
and yes thats a memory address i think the C shows its a char array and the at literally means at the address is the location in memory where the array is held.

Comment: Since arrays are classes, they extend from `Object` and do not override `toString` method, so they will use [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) (read the link to understand the result in `System.out.println(array)`).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the toString method in java not seem to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060016/why-does-the-tostring-method-in-java-not-seem-to-work)

Comment: @tieTYT Not a duplicate. This one ask's why `System.out.println(str);` prints the value in the array, not the value of `str.toString();`.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu Yes, but if you look at the accepted answer, it answers his questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the information that i get by printing an Object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696103/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-information-that-i-get-by-printing-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `[C` means that it's a character array (`[` means array; `C` means `char`), and `@4367e003` means it's at the memory address<sup>[1]</sup> `4367e003`. If you want a string that represents that character array, try `new String(str)`.
2. [`println` is overloaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()); there is also a `println` that accepts a character array. If you don't pass a primitive, `String`, or `char[]`, it will then call `toString` on the object since there's a separate overload for `System.out.println(Object)`. [Here is the documentation for the specific method that takes a character array.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[]))

   Here are the overloads for `println` (straight from the docs):

   ```
   void println()
   void println(boolean x)
   void println(char x)
   void println(char[] x)
   void println(double x)
   void println(float x)
   void println(int x)
   void println(long x)
   void println(Object x)
   void println(String x)
   ```

   You can read more about overloading at the bottom of [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

---

<sup>[1]: Technically, it's actually the hex representation of the object's hash code, but this is typically implemented by using the memory address. Note that it's not always really the memory address; sometimes that doesn't fit in an `int`. More info [in this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744735/java-array-hashcode-implementation).</sup>

Comment: It's a typical mistake to believe that the number in the default toString representation is an address. In fact, it is the hexadecimal representation of the object's hash code.

Answer (score 3):

It is calling `toString()` on the object.  The object is an array that doesn't override the [`toString()` method coming from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).  Object's implementation:

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

The `[C` means array (`[`) of char (`C`).  The [Javadocs for `Class#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) explain it in more detail.

The `4367e003` is the [object's hash code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), which is likely to be the memory address.

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)

When you don't call `toString()`, you are actually calling the [`println` method that takes a `char[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28char%5b%5d%29), which knows how to print out the chars.

Answer (score 1):

It's the reference to your array that gets printed out as a string. What you want is `Arrays.toString(str)`. And don't forget to import the `Arrays` class.

Answer (score 1):

> What does [C@4367e003 stands for ? Is it a memory address ? What's the meaning of the digits ? What's the meaning of [C@ ?

This is the [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) representation of a character array

- `[` signifies an array
- `C` is an encoding character indicating a primitive character array (all encodings found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29))
- `4367e003` is Hexadecimal depresentation of the character arrays Object hashcode

> I always thought that calling println() on an object would call the toString method of this object but it doesn't seems to be the case ?

It does call `toString` but since the primitive character array `str` does not override toString to it calls `Object#toString` To see the contents of the array you can wrap the array in a new `String` using `new String(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first println() is printing out the toString() method of a character array. The default implementation of toString() is printing a `[`, a `C` for char, the `@` symbol, and then the hash code of the array which is by default the array's memory address.